# Element whose value is smallest in a given row and highest in the corresponding column

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a square matrix has element whose value is smallest in a given row and highest in the corresponding column then it's symmetric matrix has the same property.

As an example the statement holds true for this matrix and its symmetric. The largest element of the first column is the smallest element of the first row, and for it's symmetric, the largest element of the second column is the smallest of the corresponding row.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 7 \\
5 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 5 \\
7 & 4
\end{bmatrix}

I believe this statement to be true, since I've done some case work for $2 \times 2$ matrices, but it gets pretty tedious for the higher order. In the case the matrix $A$ is $3 \times 3$ then the entries of the matrix $A$ and it's symmetric matrix $B$ look  like:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
a & d & g \\
b & e & h \\
c & f & i \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The largest elements of each column for $A$ are

$\max \{a,d,g\}, \max \{b,e,h\}, \max \{c,f,i\}$

while the smallest of each row are $\min \{a,b,c\}, \min \{b,e,h\}, \min \{c,f,i\}$

For it's symmetric matrix, the functions $\min$ and $\max$ are reversed:

$\min \{a,d,g\}, \min \{b,e,h\}, \min \{c,f,i\}$ are the smallest of each row while $\max \{a,b,c\}, \max \{b,e,h\}, \max \{c,f,i\}$ are largest of each column.

Now, we could choose something like $\max \{a,d,g\}=\min \{a,b,c \}=a$ and do bunch of casework to prove that $B$ also has the same property but this doesn't seem like a great idea.

I wonder if there is a clean method, perhaps something obvious I am missing that can be used to prove at least the simpler cases , and possibly even generalize it for any dimension of the square matrix $A$.

Note that I don't know if this holds true for every square matrix, so a counter example would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is true for $2\times 2$ matrices, for $n=3$ take $\begin{pmatrix}10&11&12\\9&8&6\\8&9&5\end{pmatrix}$